# Path file for opening files in activityforresult android 8

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

Im trying to get the path file for showing in a recycler view using intent for choosing file and activityresult for response of that action so my code works in android 4> until 7< and it works fine for those versions but in 7>= there is a problem with that code , especially in android 9.

```
public void openGallery() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "),
                SettingsUtil.ACTIVITY_GALLERY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SettingsUtil.ACTIVITY_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        String code = year + "-" + reservation + "-" + (counter++);
         File auxFile = new File(picturePath);

    }
}
```

i expect to    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); get the path like old android vesions 4+ <7 but in those new versions there is a problem there when working in last versions